# Calling angular service from ES6 class method

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

(Im using Babel to be able to use ES6)

When I call `addConfigurationToCart()` I get:

> ReferenceError: Order is not defined.

But in the constructor I don't. Why is that? I get the same error if I add Order as a parameter to `addConfigurationToCart`

```
class ConfigCtrl {
    constructor($state, api, Order) {
        this.current = Order.current;
    }

    addConfigurationToCart() {
        Order.saveConfiguration();
        $state.go('order');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, in the constructor there's an `Order` parameter that you seem to pass something. Do you want to use the same value in your method? Please show us how you are invoking this code.

Comment: @bergi Order is an angular service. Order.saveConfiguration is a method that I want to call from addConfigurationToCart. addConfigurationToCart is called on ng-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constructor` and `addConfigurationToCart` functions have different scopes (in JS sense), and sure, the variable from one scope isn't available in another, unless the variable is assigned to either `this` property or the variable from parent scope.

Private variables are still aren't there in ES2015+, but there are [some workarounds](http://modernweb.com/2014/01/20/private-variables-in-javascript-with-es6-weakmaps/) to do that.

The most obvious way is using local variables:

```
let $state, api, Order;

class ConfigCtrl {
  static $inject = ['$state', 'api', 'Order'];

  constructor(...args) {
    [$state, api, Order] = [...args];
    // ...
  }

  addConfigurationToCart() {
    Order.saveConfiguration();
    // ...
  }
}
```

And more idiomatic approach that successfully provides private variables within class:

```
const [$state, api, Order] = [Symbol(), Symbol(), Symbol()];

class ConfigCtrl {
  static $inject = ['$state', 'api', 'Order'];

  constructor(...args) {
    [$state, api, Order].forEach((v, i) => this[v] = args[i]);
    // ...
  }

  addConfigurationToCart() {
    this[Order].saveConfiguration();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the Service public to the rest of your class.

```
class ConfigCtrl {
  constructor($state, api, Order) {
      ...
      this.Order = Order;
  }

  addConfigurationToCart() {
      this.Order.saveConfiguration();
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: is there really no better looking way? that feels so ugly

Comment: @tobbe: What does feel ugly about this?

Comment: It looks neat, but the problem is that Angular controllers weren't designed with classes in mind. ES6 controllers are extensively used in conjunction with controllerAs which efficiently eliminates $scope, and that feels great. But now everything on 'this' is exposed to scope. Is it that great to pollute the scope with services? Say hello to name collisions and screwed encapsulation. Child scopes will inherit these artifacts also but who cares.

Answer (score 1):

```
controller: class {
    constructor($http, Restangular, $state) {
        Object.assign(this, {$http, Restangular, $state});
    }
    doIt() {
       // use this.$http, this.Restangular & this.$state freely here
    }
}
```